# Help on how to read and understand a question on vector space and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

V is a vector space, S is its subset. Determine if the following subsets are its subspace:

$$\begin{align} &S_1=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|x_1+x_2...+x_n=0\};V=\Bbb R^n \\
 &S_2=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|x_1x_2=0\};V=\Bbb R^n \end{align}$$

I'm not sure I understand how to read this. This is how far I got, for $S_1$:

$u=(a_1,...,a_n)  \\v=(b_1,...,b_n) $

And to determine whether or not its a subspace we use:

$\alpha u+ \beta v \in S : \forall \alpha,\beta \in S  : \forall u, v \in S$

Now I don't know how to use the right side of the given subset here ($|x_1+x_2...+x_n=0$). Same with $S_2$.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be in $\mathbb{R}$ correct?

Comment: They should be in the same field as V if I'm not mistaken. This is just from definition though, I have no info about them in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_1$: Note $S_1 \neq \varnothing$ because $(0, \dotsc, 0) \in S_1$.  Next, choose two elements $x = (x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \dotsc, y_n)$ in $S_1$.  Then $x + y \in S_1$, because
$$ \sum_i (x_i + y_i) = \sum_i x_i + \sum_i y_i = 0. $$
Similarly, $\alpha x \in S_1$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ because
$$ \sum_i \alpha x_i = \alpha \sum_i x_i = 0. $$
Thus, $S_1$ is a subspace of $V$.

I claim that $S_2$ is not a subspace of $V$ because $e_1 = (1, 0, \dotsc, 0) \in S_2$ and $e_2 = (0, 1, \dotsc, 0) \in S_2$, but $e_1 + e_2 = (1, 1, \dotsc, 0) \notin S_2$.

Comment: This is exactly what I did for $S_1$ in the first place but then I erased it because I thought I was wrong. When you sum x and y, doesn't it look like this: $(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2...x_n+y_n)$ ? So according to the right side of the subset, this isn't equal 0.

Comment: Right, when you add $x$ and $y$ you obtain $(x_1 + y_1, \dotsc, x_n + y_n)$.  Now what does it mean for $x + y$ to be an element of $S_1$?  It means that the sum of the coordinates is $0$.  That is, $\sum_i (x_i + y_i) = 0$, which does indeed hold.